# Apple Push Notifications - App store submission

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using a third party library which has code for push notifications. But in our code, we don't have anything related to push notifications. So my profile is not enabled with APNS. When I try to push this to iTunes Connect for BETA TESTING, I'm getting below email from Apple. My question now is **CAN I SUBMIT MY APP WITH APNS ENABLED even when I am not using push notifications?**  **Will Apple reject my app if I do so?**

> Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   delivery for "Myapp Beta". Your delivery was successful, but you may
>   wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: Missing
>   Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used
>   to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
>   signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API. After you’ve corrected
>   the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new
>   binary to iTunes Connect. Regards, The App Store team

Comment: Just enable the app for push notifications, in the build settings in the project in XCode there is a flick switch to turn it on. Then try the submission again, if that still gets rejected you'll need to enable push in your provisioning profile and rebuild it and submit it again. There's lots of tutorials on how to enable the provisioning profile for push.

Comment: Mr H, can you guide to find the setting to turn on in Build Settings... I am not able to locate it.

Comment: A put the steps in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Click on your project in Xcode (near the upper left hand corner of Xcode)
2) then click on Capabilities (near the top in the middle of Xcode)
3) Scroll down to Background Modes and expand to reveal the modes
4) Select Remote Notifications.
```

Doing this will give you the push entitlement and therefore the app submission should be ok. 
Apple won't know you are not actually making use of push notifications, they will just be running a tool which detects you have push notification handling code in the app but don't have the push entitlement. Doing the above 4 steps should add the entitlement.

Hopefully that should be enough, however you may also need to enable push notifications in your provisioning profile. That's easy to do, the best overall guide to push which tells you how to do that is here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Please I received the same email and the status of my application in iTunes Connect is "Waiting For Review.". Is that meaning that the application is ok for this time and it will pass to the review then the release  or have I to make a new build resolving the issu?

Comment: @Llg "waiting for review" means exactly what it says. It means nobody has even started to review it yet.

Comment: So I don't have to correct the push problem and deliver a new build?

Comment: @Llg, I didn't read your comment properly. Its strange that you have received an email but its waiting for review. But as you know you have an identified issue, why wait, why not fix it and re-submit?

Comment: that's why I'm confused. I received this mail then after 10 minutes I received another one saying that the status of my app is "waiting for review". And what make me more confused is this sentence: "Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery"