# iOS - App Store Submission with Push Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appstore-approval

Can we submit an iOS app to app store with enabling push notification but not configuring it(adding certificates to it)?

If Yes do we need to submit the app again with newly generated profile after configuring PN?

Comment: Push certificates are for the server. To submit the app you only need that your App ID has 'Push notifications' enabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335650/apple-push-notifications-app-store-submission

Comment: Also remember that you can now test your application (including production push notifications) in TestFlight.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**,You can skip certificate configuration while submission But after adding You must resubmit the app to **Appstore** to enable push notifications

After adding the certificates only your xCode will compile with certificates and generate `ipa` with keychainAccess certificate credentials